# Remover item de array ao desmarcar checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Estou pegando o valor de um checkbox e colocando em um array `valores`, Minha dúvida é: como, ao desmarcar a caixa de seleção, remover esse valor do meu array? Porque se eu marcar e desmarcar a checkbox 10 vezes ele vai colocar o valor no array 10 vezes.

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox");
var valores = [];

checkbox.onchange = function(){
    valores.push(event.target.value);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crie uma condição para remover caso já exista no seu vetor:

```
if (valores.indexOf(event.target.value) === - 1) {
    // Se o evento não está presente no vetor, nós o adicionamos
    valores.push(event.target.value);
} else {
    // Se o evento está presente no vetor, nós o removemos
    valores.filter(function(value, index, arr){
        return value !== event.target.value;
    });
}
```

Comment: a função `pop` remove o ultimo item do array e não um item especifico...

Comment: Verdade, foi falta de atenção. Alterada e obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

antes de tudo você precisa validar se o item já esta no seu `array`

```
value_included = valores.include(event.target.value);
is_checked = event.target.checked;

// o valor já esta no array porem o checkbox não esta selecionado
if (value_included && !is_checked) {
    position = valors.indexOf(event.target.value);
    valores.splice(position, 1);
    return
}

// o valor não esta no array e o checkbox esta selecionado
if (!value_included && is_checked) {
    valores.push(event.target.value);
}
```